# Validating SSL root certs via Indy for any URL

Tags: delphi, ssl, openssl, certificate, delphi-xe8

I'm trying to validate root SSL certs in chain.
For this I load `.pem` file with 126 root certs in OpenSSL with `TIdSSLContext.RootCertFile` field. All certs succesefully loaded.

Without `.pem` file, I never seen ADepth more then 1.

When I'm trying to validate certs with requests to different URL, for some URL's in chain exists root certs with ADept >=2 e.g. Root like DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA in `OnVerifyPeer`. But most of URL's don't have certs deeper then ADepth = 1. Look at the picture below.

[image]

`OnVerifyPeer` look's like `Result := iif(ADepth >= 2, True, AOk);`

```
LWrapper.SSLHandler.SSLOptions.RootCertFile := 'filepath to .pem file';
LWrapper.SSLHandler.SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1_2;
LWrapper.SSLHandler.SSLOptions.Mode := sslmUnassigned;
LWrapper.SSLHandler.SSLOptions.VerifyMode := [sslvrfPeer];
LWrapper.SSLHandler.SSLOptions.VerifyDepth := 10;
```

What am I doing wrong to check the user’s list of root certificates for any URL?

Comment: What is your requirement? Must ADepth be at most 2? Then it is Result := iif(ADepth **<= 2**, True, AOk);

Comment: Validation starts at max ADepth cert. *->2->1->0. [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onx7B.png)
AOk parameter - validation result from openssl dll. 
I'm trying validate root certs(ADepth >= 2). 
But when root certs are loaded in openssl dll, verification does not always start from them.
If chain doesn't contain root cert, parameter AError was 27(X509_V_ERR_CERT_UNTRUSTED).